# Laravel localhost page showing the error Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder::__construct(): Argument #2 ($paths) must be of type array, null given,

Tags: laravel

My localhost laravel is showing the below error:

```
TypeError

Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder::__construct(): Argument #2 ($paths) must be of type array, null given, called in F:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php on line 84
```

PHP 8.1.2
Laravel 10.24.0

Here is F:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php file LINE 84

```
/**
 * Register the view finder implementation.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function registerViewFinder()
{
    $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
        return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], $app['config']['view.paths']);
    });
}
```

I am loading 127.0.0.1:8000 page in localhost.
Yesterday it was loading fine.
I am running php artisan serve.

[image: here is screenshot of the error page]

Here is view.php file in config folder

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),

];
```

Comment: It seems your view path is wrong, can you post the contents of your `config/view.php` file please. Or you may have misconfigured the view path

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear:cache` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now as pointed out by Josh Bolton in the answer section here.
After I added config/view.php file and issuing

> php artisan config:clear

**The page is loading fine now.**

Comment: Can you accept the answer as correct if this fixed your issue please

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by a missing or misconfigured view config file. Either edit, or create, a file at `config/view.php` and the contents should look something similar to the below:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),

];
```